# For what is the new keyword?

Tags: swift, keyword

I read the `The Swift Programming Language` [iBook](https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l).
In the keywords section they listed `new`. But in the section `Summary of the Grammar` I didn't found it.

For what is `new` used in Swift?

Comment: In C#, I've used "new" to hide sealed methods whose behavior I didn't agree with. "new" is generally pointless in C#, however, and I'm glad Swift doesn't use it for initializers. I'm away from my Mac; please let us know if you can use "new" to "override" anything marked with @final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to have been removed.

I tried `let x = new Double[2]` but in Xcode 7 it now throws an error

> Playground execution failed: OSX.playground:1:9: error: use of unresolved identifier 'new'
>   let a = new [Double]

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `new` can be used to create an array:

```
let x = new Double[2]
x[0] = 3.1
x[1] = 4.2
println(x)
// Output: [3.1, 4.2]
```

But this is only of theoretical interest. It is not documented and should therefore not be
used.